# Iterate Docs on Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I insert in mongodb with mongoose an array of elements with insertMany function. All goes fine, but I need to take for each element his id. When I insert these elements, i receive an array of docs but i can't iterate them.

Do you have Any solution?

Code example:

```
const docsExamples = await Examples.insertMany(req.body.examples);
```

Comment: Can you fully explain?

Comment: I think i get a better solution, not using insertMany but insert each element in db with the new Method

Comment: But you can use insertmany like this ‛insertmany(name:req.body.name)‛

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` on the array of docs that is returned by insertMany to return a new array of just the ids like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const Test = mongoose.model('test', schema);

const tests = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tests.push(new Test({ name: `test${i}`}));
}

async function run() {
  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
  const docs = await Test.insertMany(tests);
  const ids = docs.map(d => d.id);
  console.log(ids);
  return mongoose.connection.close();
}

run();
```

output:

```
stack: ./49852063.js
[ '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd3',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd4',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd5',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd6',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd7',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd8',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fd9',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fda',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fdb',
  '5ad47da0f38fec9807754fdc' ]
stack:
```